# Balanced triplet brackets

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

A "triplet bracket" (that I made up for this challenge) is one of the following:

```
(...+...)
[...:...]
{...|...}
<...-...>
```

A balanced triplet bracket string (BTBS for short) is either an empty string, two BTBSes concatenated, or one of the above triplet brackets with each `...` replaced with a BTBS.

Your task is to write a program or function that checks whether a string that consists of only `(+)[:]{|}<->` is balanced. Shortest code wins.

### Examples

Your program should return truthy for the following strings:

```
(+)(+)(+)
[[[:]:]:(+(+))]{<->|<(+)->[:]}(+)
<<<<<<<<<<<<->->->->->->->->->->->->
{|(+[:<-{|(+[:<->])}>])}
[[[:]:[:]]:[[:]:[:]]]
{[:](+)|<->{|}}[(+)<->:{|}(+)]
```

Your program should return falsy for the following strings:

```
:[
<|>
(+(+)
[:][:](+[[:]):]
{|{|{|(+{|{|{|}}}}}+)}[:]{|}
{{||}}
<<->-<->-<->>
[(+):((+)+)+(+(+))]
<<<<<->->->->->->
```

Comment: Is `(|)` valid. I don't think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: @RomanGräf No, as `<|>` in the falsy examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Japt, 25 bytes

```
!Ue"%(%+%)|%[:]|\{%|}|<->
```

[**Test it online!**](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=IVVlIiUoJSslKXwlWzpdfFx7JXx9fDwtPg==&input=IntbOl0oKyl8PC0+e3x9fVsoKyk8LT46e3x9KCspXSI=)

`e` on strings is a recursive-replace function. The second parameter defaults to the empty string, which means this recursively removes matches of the Japt regex `"%(%+%)|%[:]|\{%|}|<->"` (in regular terms, `/\(\+\)|\[:]|{\|}|<->/`). This returns an empty string for balanced triplet strings and a non-empty string for non-balanced, so the correct return value is the logical NOT of this.

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```js
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/\(\+\)|\[:]|{\|}|<->/,''))?!s:f(s)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/\(\+\)|\[:]|{\|}|<->/,''))?!s:f(s)

console.log("Testing truthy values");
console.log(f("(+)(+)(+)"));
console.log(f("[[[:]:]:(+(+))]{<->|<(+)->[:]}(+)"));
console.log(f("<<<<<<<<<<<<->->->->->->->->->->->->"));
console.log(f("{|(+[:<-{|(+[:<->])}>])}"));
console.log(f("[[[:]:[:]]:[[:]:[:]]]"));
console.log(f("{[:](+)|<->{|}}[(+)<->:{|}(+)]"));

console.log("Testing falsy values");
console.log(f(":["));
console.log(f("<|>"));
console.log(f("(+(+)"));
console.log(f("[:][:](+[[:]):]"));
console.log(f("{|{|{|(+{|{|{|}}}}}+)}[:]{|}"));
console.log(f("{{||}}"));
console.log(f("<<->-<->-<->>"));
console.log(f("[(+):((+)+)+(+(+))]"));
console.log(f("<<<<<->->->->->->"));
```

Comment: The same idea in Retina is 26 bytes (the first line just makes it a test suite): http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAorYFwoXCtcKXxcWzpdfHtcfH18PC0-CgpeJA&input=KCspKCspKCspCltbWzpdOl06KCsoKykpXXs8LT58PCgrKS0-WzpdfSgrKQo8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDwtPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4Ke3woK1s6PC17fCgrWzo8LT5dKX0-XSl9CltbWzpdOls6XV06W1s6XTpbOl1dXQp7WzpdKCspfDwtPnt8fX1bKCspPC0-Ont8fSgrKV0KOlsKPHw-CigrKCspCls6XVs6XSgrW1s6XSk6XQp7fHt8e3woK3t8e3x7fH19fX19Kyl9Wzpde3x9Cnt7fHx9fQo8PC0-LTwtPi08LT4-ClsoKyk6KCgrKSspKygrKCspKV0KPDw8PDwtPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4

Comment: And 39 with perl : `perl -lpe 's/<->|\(\+\)|{\|}|\[:]//&&redo;$_=!$_'`.

Comment: @Dada That will consider `0` a BTBS. Use this 38 instead: `perl -pe 's/<->|\(\+\)|{\|}|\[:]//&&redo;$_=/^$/'`

Comment: @TonHospel Didn't thought of that, indeed.. thanks for pointing it out! (feel free to post it if you want by the way, or at least don't hold back because of me)

Comment: That S/s mix was slightly confusing, perhaps `f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(...))?!s:f(s)`?

Comment: @Neil I'm personally not sure if `s==(s=s.replace(...))` is really more readable, but I like the idea of not introducing an extra variable anyway.

Answer (score 5):

## sed, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
:
s#(+)\|\[:]\|{|}\|<->##
t
```

*sed* doesn't have a concept of truthy/falsy, so I'm considering an empty string truthy and a non-empty string falsy. This checks out if we consider the conditional `/^$/`.

*Thanks to @Neil for golfing off 1 byte!*

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=OgpzIygrKVx8XFs6XVx8e3x9XHw8LT4jIwp0&input=KCspKCspKCspCltbWzpdOl06KCsoKykpXXs8LT58PCgrKS0-WzpdfSgrKQo8PDw8PDw8PDw8PDwtPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4Ke3woK1s6PC17fCgrWzo8LT5dKX0-XSl9CltbWzpdOls6XV06W1s6XTpbOl1dXQp7WzpdKCspfDwtPnt8fX1bKCspPC0-Ont8fSgrKV0KOlsKPHw-CigrKCspCls6XVs6XSgrW1s6XSk6XQp7fHt8e3woK3t8e3x7fH19fX19Kyl9Wzpde3x9Cnt7fHx9fQo8PC0-LTwtPi08LT4-ClsoKyk6KCgrKSspKygrKCspKV0KPDw8PDwtPi0-LT4tPi0-LT4)

Comment: For once, BRE is actually an *advantage*.

Comment: Do you need the `\]` or does `]` suffice?

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 77 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval("s"+".replace('%s','')"*4%('(+)','[:]','{|}','<->')*len(s))==''
```

Uses [Arnauld's replacement idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97071/20260). Generates and evaluates a long string like

```python
s.replace('(+)','').replace('[:]','').replace('{|}','').replace('<->','').replace('(+)','').replace('[:]','').replace('{|}','').replace('<->','')
```

to cycle between replacing all the bracket types. Then, checks if the result is the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
StringDelete["(+)"|"[:]"|"{|}"|"<->"]~FixedPoint~#==""&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input and returns `True` or `False` as output. Uses the standard method for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 39 bytes

```
e`\(_\+_\)|\[_\:_\]|\{_\|_\}|\<_\-_\>v*
```

[Try it online!](http://grime.tryitonline.net/#code=ZWBcKF9cK19cKXxcW19cOl9cXXxce19cfF9cfXxcPF9cLV9cPnYq&input=WygrKTwtPjpde3x9) Sadly, the TIO version runs out of memory on most of the test cases.

### Explanation

Nothing too fancy here.
`_` is shorthand for the entire pattern, and `v*` is the same as `*`, but with lower precedence.

```
e`                                       Match entire input against this pattern:
  \(_\+_\)                               '(', match of _, '+', match of _, ')'
          |                              or
           \[_\:_\]|\{_\|_\}|\<_\-_\>    same for the other bracket types
                                     v*  repeated 0-∞ times
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 48 bytes

```
a:=([:delstring&.>/'(+)';'[:]';'{|}';'<->';])^:_
```

Similar to the others, this is also based on Arnauld's [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97071/6710).

### Usage

```
   f =: a:=([:delstring&.>/'(+)';'[:]';'{|}';'<->';])^:_
   f '(+)(+)(+)'
1
   f '[[[:]:]:(+(+))]{<->|<(+)->[:]}(+)'
1
   f '<<<<<<<<<<<<->->->->->->->->->->->->'
1
   f '<|>'
0
   f '[:][:](+[[:]):]'
0
   f '{|{|{|(+{|{|{|}}}}}+)}[:]{|}'
0
```

### Explanation

```
a:=([:delstring&.>/'(+)';'[:]';'{|}';'<->';])^:_  Input: string S
   (                                        )^:_  Repeat until convergence
                                         ]          Get S
                 '(+)';'[:]';'{|}';'<->';           Append to ['(+)', '[:]', '{|}', '<->']
    [:delstring&.>/                                 Reduce right-to-left by deleting
                                                    occurrences of each string on the
                                                    left from the right
                                                    Return the final string as the new S
a:=                                               Test if the final value of S is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 26 bytes

```
L#aaR:"(+)[:]{|}<->"<>3x!a
```

[Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=TCNhYVI6IigrKVs6XXt8fTwtPiI8PjN4IWE&input=&args=e3x7fHt8KCt7fHt8e3x9fX19fSspfVs6XXt8fQ)

Loops len(a) times, replacing all occurrences of empty triplet brackets (`"(+)[:]{|}<->"<>3`, where `<>` is the "group" operator, => `["(+)"; "[:]"; "{|}"; "<->"]`) with empty string (`x`). This many iterations is overkill, but it will always be more than enough to completely reduce all properly formed triplet brackets to nothing. After the loop completes, outputs `!a`: `0` if `a` is truthy (still has some characters), `1` if `a` is falsey (empty).

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 96 bytes

```
def&(s:String):Any={val t=s.replaceAll(raw"\(\+\)|\[:]|\{\|}|<->","")
if(t==s)t.size<1 else&(t)}
```

This is basically the same idea as the other answers, but with some scala boilerplate.

#### without stealing ideas from others (188 bytes):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
val a = new RegexParsers{def r:Parser[_]="("~r~"+"~r~")"|"["~r~":"~r~"]"|"{"~r~"|"~r~"}"|"<"~r~"-"~r~">"|""
def!(s:String)= !parseAll(r,s).isEmpty}!_
```